# ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following input: RaggedTensor

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, cnn, numpy

I have following inputs to be trained on a CNN:

```
x = np.array(Images)


y = [ [[0]], [[76.,  5.,  9., 1.,  0.,  0.],  [54.,  4., 10., 51.]] ]
```

Since the `y` input is a n-dimensions array of non-uniform lengths, I used RaggedTensor to represent the `y` input and fed it to the network.

```
y = tf.ragged.constant(y)


cnn_model.fit(x, y, epochs = 10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.30)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor'>]
```

If I convert `y` to a `numpy.ndarray` and fit it to the model, I got the following error:

```
cnn_model.fit(x, y.numpy(), epochs = 10, batch_size=32,
                    validation_split=0.30) 


ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I would like to train this input `y` of n-dimensional array to the model. Kindly suggest which datatype representation would be suitable regarding this.

Comment: Why do you need outputs with different shapes?

Comment: The y input is the description of SIFT key point features corresponding to each image in x. I want to perform binary classification on given inputs(x-images & y-SIFT descriptors). Hence I would want to predict SIFT features for a given image.

Comment: In that case, I think you'd need an RNN to produce a sequence based on the image. The idea is similar to image labelling.